# Android Emulator API21 not starting

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

[image: android 5.0 emulator]

android 5.0 emulator not starting on my 32bit ubuntu.

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google'
>   ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
>          you will have to do at least one of the following:
>          - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
>          - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
>          Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
>          aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
>          Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

I tried with *-force-32bit* option..it starts endless loading android logo on emulator. Never goes to home screen. what to do?

**UPDATE**-
Ok. i was able to start x86 arch. emulator using **KVM** but now the **proxy settings** not working in emulator. Can't connect to internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set `Internal Storage` to 4GB, which can delay the emulator startup, reducing the size may help.

In general, the android emulator can be slow depending on your system/configuration, it takes a long time to boot up initially. [Consider using Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture) (available under extras in Android SDK Manager) or something [like genymotion if it satisfies your requirements](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: HAXM does not supported for LINUX(Ubuntu)

Comment: @ArnavM on Linux you can [use kvm please see this on how-to](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator)

Comment: KVM method worked for x86 architecture...even genymotion needs Ubuntu 12.04... mine is ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

**You may use**

- intel Atom(X86) in the CPU/AIB configuration instead of ARM(armeabi-v7a)
- reduce the size of the internal storage
- mark (checked) use gpu host
- And Add new Configuration by right click to project->change run configuration ->go to the target tab then type **-force-32bit** at command box and then -> run

It solved my Problem Hope It solves your's ass well

> Thanks for @Ashoke his answer is also helpful

Comment: but after following your steps it stucks

Comment: try it by increasing the internal storage